# Simple way for a store view distribution page

Tags: cms, stores

We have an international store and the option to include the store view URL, i.e. URLs like

- http://www.example.com/de
- http://www.example.com/us
- http://www.example.com/et

When the user opens, http://www.example.com/ we want to show an entry page with links to the different countries.

How to accomplish that?

My current approaches:

1. Create an additional store view "landing", edit the CMS page "home" (I think I would need some tweaks to show this store view under the `/` URL)
2. Or set the setting `web/default/cms_home_page` globally to a CMS page, lets say "landingpage". Overwrite it in the real stores.
3. ???

*Edit - additional:* In our case we also use the "default" site as a template (for CMS pages) which we copy to the different countries - so this site is kind of impossible to use in production.

*Edit - see* @kalenjordan commeting on my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is my final solution based on the community answers:

1. Create global_website and store code: `global`
2. Create CMS page `home` in Global Website
3. Change `MAGE_RUN_CODE` env variable in vhost or .htaccess. Alternative in `index.php`, change default store code to `global` (`$mageRunCode = 'global'`)
4. Add Layout updates for the handle `STORE_global` to remove unneeded parts of the layout (for example the main menu)

Disclaimer:

Changing the `index.php` can lead to complications, you have to be careful during updates to merge your changes properly.

Comment: why not use a virtual host configuration instead of changing `index.php`?

Comment: @Tim: I have a reason for that :-) But in general I suggest vhost or .htaccess. *edited*

Comment: In regard to the store codes.  Shouldn't we be using full locale codes and not just language codes.  For example, de-de, ca-en, ca-fr.  Looks like Magento doesn't allow dashes in the store code, but only underscores.

Comment: Hm - yes. I see, this questions is a bit broader :-) Feel free to add an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it:

- Base url `example.com` (root, no language selected) would be the 'default' site as installed by Magento, i.e. the one with the store code 'default'.
- The homepage for `default` is your 'select a store' gateway CMS page
- That links to the subdirectories, which are *physical* directories in the webroot that have symlinked `media`, `skin`, `js` directories; index.php is a separate file that references `../app/Mage.php` instead of `app/Mage.php`
- The htaccess in subdirectories will define the store and run codes

Ideally your default site's root catalog is empty. The CMS homepage's custom layout xml could remove things like nav, header, footer. You could also have some customization in index.php to check for a `store` cookie so as to push them to their preferred site on future visits instead of requiring them to step through the language/locale gateway.

Comment: I've taken this approach before and I approve. +1.

Comment: Hm - I would prefer a simpler solution - already happy I do not need subdirectories by using Magento's "include store code in URL" feature.

Comment: I've never used that feature - definitely intrigued now.

Comment: Alias directive in vhost config: `Alias /en "/path/to/vhost/root` should work for Apache, and I've just yesterday seen similar technique in nginx config.

Comment: You can also set `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and/or `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` in `.htaccess` with `SetEnvIf` instead of having physical directories and index.php and .htaccess copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with 1st approach. In a meanwhile you may want to add more pages irrelevant to any of localised store views or make some other customisations. This approach will give you a bit more flexibility.

Comment: +1 for future flexibility. Is there a non-hacky way to direct `example.com` to this `example.com/landing`.

Comment: self-answer: I think changing MAGE_RUN_CODE is easy and can be done in the .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

A third option would be to rewrite the url `http://www.example.com` to the homepages or a different CMS page on any of the stores. So `http://www.example.com` would be rewritten to `http://www.example.com/us/landing.html`.

I've never tried it before but it should basically work. Magento would pick up on the full URL and process it as a normal CMS page